# Check an AlertDialog's title and message

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

With Espresso is it possible to simplify those two statements ?

```
    onView(withText(expectedErrorTitle))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withText(expectedErrorMessage))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

I tried with this one but it doesn't work :

```
    onView(allOf(
            withText(expectedErrorTitle),
            withText(expectedErrorMessage)
    )).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why simplify more? But you could check on a parent view to have children with expected text.

```
onView(R.id.parentLayout)
  .check(matches(allOf(
    isDisplayed(), 
    withChild(withText("A")),
    withChild(withText("B"))
)));
```

Checking that the parent is displayed could be enough or you do more crazy stuff like

```
onView(R.id.parentLayout)
  .check(matches(allOf(
    withChild(allOf(withText("A"), isDisplayed())),
    withChild(allOf(withText("B"), isDisplayed())),
)));
```